# While loop in Android studio (button)

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I have a button which is let users when open the application then can use the function.

This is the function:

```
  if(eyeDected)
        {
            if(detectedFrame > 25)
            {
                eyeDected = false;
                detectedFrame = 0;
                finish();
            } else {
                detectedFrame++;
                Log.d("UNLOCK:", String.valueOf(detectedFrame));
            }
        } else {
            eyeDected = true;
            detectedFrame++;
            Log.d("UNLOCK:", String.valueOf(detectedFrame));
        }
```

I want do a while loop function:  (the number of click is a,b,c) (For example b=1 is mean that user click once time only)

```
a=0
b=1
c=2

when 'a' = 0,3,6,9,12,15..... (mean 'a'+3) then run the function
when 'b' = 1,4,7,10 ,13....(mean b+3) then run the function
when 'c' = 2,5,8,11,16... (mean b+3) then run the function
```

How can　i　perform a while loop for these? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add following condition :

```
a=0
b=1
c=2
```

when 'a' = 0,3,6,9,12 (mean 'a'+3) then run a function

```
if(a%3 == 0){
// run a function
}
```

when 'b' = 1,4,7,10 (mean b+3) then run a function

```
if((b+1)%3 == 0){
// run B function
}
```

when 'c' = 2,5,8,11 (mean b+3) then run a function

```
if((c+2)%3 == 0){
// run B function
}
```

Ex. in loop :

```
for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
   if( i % 3 == 0){
      // run a function
   }
   else if( (i+1) % 3 == 0){
      // run b function
   }
   else if( (i+2) % 3 == 0){
      // run c function
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering. I need declare the variable for a,b and c or not? mean before a=0 need to write : @override and  private class?

Comment: then a,b,c what class need declare? can u tell a full coding? sorry, i'm basic learning

Comment: Hi, correct ?int counter = 0 // button press set to zero

@Override
Public void Oncreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.oncreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.??);

public void countIN(){

do(){
if (counter == 1|counter == 4|counter == 7){
//execute the code
};
else if (counter == 2|counter == 5|counter == 8){
//execute the code
};
else (counter == 3|counter == 6|counter == 9){
//execute the code

while(counter ++);
}